# foxy can't launch gazebo11 model and report SyntaxError

Tags: ros2, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, I'm trying to use the foxy to launch the simulation environment(gazebo11) on the ubuntu20.04，but can not load the robot model  and report an error.
The error is as follows：

```
 [spawn_entity.py-4] Traceback (most recent call last):
[spawn_entity.py-4]   File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py", line 27, in <module>
[spawn_entity.py-4]     from gazebo_msgs.msg import ModelStates
[spawn_entity.py-4]   File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gazebo_msgs/msg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[spawn_entity.py-4]     from gazebo_msgs.msg._contact_state import ContactState  # noqa: F401
[spawn_entity.py-4]   File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gazebo_msgs/msg/_contact_state.py", line 11, in <module>
[spawn_entity.py-4]     import rosidl_parser.definition  # noqa: E402, I100
[spawn_entity.py-4]   File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rosidl_parser/definition.py", line 426
[spawn_entity.py-4]     raise ValueError(f"No '{name}' annotation")
[spawn_entity.py-4]                                              ^
[spawn_entity.py-4] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[ERROR] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has died [pid 4442, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py --ros-args -r __node:=urdf_spawner'].
```

---

I want to use String.format(name) solve the problem,but it will report more error。such as :

```
[spawn_entity.py-4]     import rclpy
[spawn_entity.py-4]   File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
[spawn_entity.py-4]     from rclpy.utilities import get_default_context
[spawn_entity.py-4]   File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/utilities.py", line 98
[spawn_entity.py-4]     f'The RMW implementations {missing_rmw_implementations}
```

and

```
[spawn_entity.py-4]     from rclpy.node import Node
[spawn_entity.py-4]   File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/node.py'',line 146
[spawn_entity.py-4]     self.__subcriptions: List[Subcription]=[]
[spawn_entity.py-4]     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

my laucnh file code:

---

```
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription

from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, ExecuteProcess,IncludeLaunchDescription

from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration

from launch_ros.actions import Node

from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

def generate_launch_description():

  use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='false')

  urdf_file_name = '/home/zys/ros2_prj/AGV_SIM_WS/src/urdf_tutorial_r2d2/urdf/agv_car.urdf'

  package_name = 'urdf_tutorial_r2d2'

  pkg_gazebo_ros = get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros')

  print("urdf_file_name : {}".format(urdf_file_name))

  urdf = os.path.join(
      get_package_share_directory('urdf_tutorial_r2d2'),
      urdf_file_name)

  with open(urdf, 'r') as infp:
        robot_desc = infp.read()

  return LaunchDescription([

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='false',
            description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),

        ExecuteProcess(
            # cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'],
            cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '/home/zys/ros2_prj/AGV_SIM_WS/src/urdf_tutorial_r2d2/sim_world/box_house.world'],
            output='screen'),

        Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,'robot_description': robot_desc}],
            arguments=[urdf]),

        Node(
            package='joint_state_publisher',
            executable='joint_state_publisher',
            name='joint_state_publisher',
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time, 'robot_description': robot_desc}],
            output='screen',
            ),

        Node(
            package='gazebo_ros',
            executable='spawn_entity.py',
            name='urdf_spawner',
            output='screen',
            # arguments=["-topic", "/robot_description", "-entity", -f"AGV_CAR"])
            # arguments=['-entity',
            #        'mobot',
            #        '-x', '3.5', '-y', '1.0', '-z', '0.1',
            #        '-file', urdf
            #          ]

            )
  ])
```

---

my running enviroment:

---

```
Linux ubuntu20.04

gazebo11

ROS_VERSION=2

ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
```

ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0

ROS_DISTRO=foxy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399737/foxy-can%27t-launch-gazebo11-model-and-report-syntaxerror./) by [zhangys](https://answers.ros.org/users/103348/zhangys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> raise ValueError(f"No '{name}' annotation")

I think the `gazebo_ros` `spawn_entity.py` wants a name. You have a name in there, which you commented out. It uses `-entity` to request a name.

However, you have it in there twice. first as  `"-entity", -f"AGV_CAR"` which I am not quite sure how to interpret that.

And second

```
    # arguments=['-entity',
    #        'mobot',
```

Which would spawn a robot called `mobot`.

I'm not sure why you commented those lines out? I don't think `spawn_entity` uses `-file` anymore. It used to be possible to use `-file` to give the URDF file, but it has switched to using a `topic` (for instance `robot_description` as you have used, but you might want to remove the `/`).

I hope this helps, otherwise drop a comment.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhangys](https://answers.ros.org/users/103348/zhangys/) on 2022-04-28**:
Thanks,you are right ! My launch file's arguments  have some error,but I had modified.but it still gives an error.Fortunately,The reason I found this error is because I installed conda virtual environment.

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-04-29**:
Glad to help, do I understand correctly that you still have an error in your launch file?

**Comment by [zhangys](https://answers.ros.org/users/103348/zhangys/) on 2022-04-29**:
oh,no, The erro had be updated.There has no error in may launch file now!